# How to align menu position inside nav tag

Tags: html, css, alignment, html-lists

I have a problem with align a navigation menu in `CSS/HTML`.

I have code: [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/062qjyzk/). 
The prolbem is that, I can't align the menu inside the nav tag.
Please help!

Comment: Please refine your question. How do you want it aligned? Paste your HTML/CSS for this specific problem into your question.

Comment: How exactly you want to align it ?

Answer (score 0):

You need to add `margin: 0 auto` to your `menu_container` class,

```
div.menu_container {
   width: 500px;
  /*margin-left:auto;*/
  /*margin-right:auto;*/
  height: 50px; 
  margin: 0 auto;
}
```

[WORKING CODEPEN](http://codepen.io/Gothburz/pen/ZbjNbE)